# How do you cater for AND and OR searches in a WebApi query string?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

How do you cater for AND and OR searches in a WebApi query string using Get in C#?

For example, for searches such as `firstName=John OR firstName=Simon AND Country=UK OR Country=Canada OR LastName=Jones Or Age>=65`

Comment: [OData](https://www.odata.org)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Can you be a bit more specific?  There's a lot of information at the site you linked; you're basically quoting all of OData.  Brief guidance on the specifics in OData that pertain (bonus points for a code sample) would make a good answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Are you using EF? I managed to do this with `System.Linq.Dynamic.Core` (https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is right, WebAPI supports OData that will be the best way to do it this link provide the information on how to setup a V3 WebApi endpoint https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/

Comment: Correction on my comment, the doc provides the info to setup OData V4 EndPoint (V3 as well)

Comment: @JesusSalas: Which link in that tome points to the part that describes supporting AND and OR searches?

Comment: @RobertHarvey 'Supporting OData Query Options in Web API 2' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options). I'll expand this to an answer.

Comment: @JesusSalas: Excellent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to support this kind of queries 'properly' the best path of action is to enable OData on your WebAPI2 Controller.

The [OData in ASP.NET Web API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/) documentation provides all the information you need to configure OData V4 (V3 as well) in your WebAPI project, and provides examples on how to implement your Controllers Actions  ([Supporting OData Query Options in ASP.NET Web API 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options)s)

From the above link we can see next code snippet:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    [Queryable]
    IQueryable<Product> Get() {}
}
```

How the Get() implementation looks when you are using Entity Framework?

```
 public class ProductsController : ApiController
 {
    [Queryable]
    IQueryable<Product> Get() {
       var ef = new myDbContext(); 
       return ef.Products; // <-- DbSet<Product>
    }
 }
```

And how a query string will look to query this WebAPI EndPoint?

```
https://[domain]/api/v1/Products?$filter=firstName eq 'john' or firstName eq 'Simon' and country eq 'UK'
```

Is as simple as the above because the .Net OData stack will parse out of the box the $filter (and any other querystring element that is supported by the OData specification) and apply the query (and the others) to the IQueryable object by itself

If you are not using EF, or any other system that provides access to a IQueryable you can intercept this out-of-the-box behavior and get full control of how this parsing happen to adapt the execution to your needs.